# error numero par o impar

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy haciendo un programa en **SQL SERVER** el cual me imprima si es par o impar

```
DECLARE @a INT = 4
DECLARE @b INT = 2
DECLARE @resultado INT 
SELECT @resultado = @a % @b
IF @resultado = 0
|BEGIN 
 PRINT @resultado
 END
 ELSE IF @resultado = 1
 BEGIN
 PRINT @resultado
 END
 ELSE
 BEGIN
 PRINT 'ERROR'
 END
```

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 40
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'.
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 43
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.

Comment: Y por qué necesitas esos bloques de transacción BEGIN..END?

Comment: Tienes una línea antes del primer BEGIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que tienes un carácter extraño (un pipe) antes del primer `BEGIN`. De todas formas, lo puedes escribir también sin esos `BEGIN` / `END`:

```
DECLARE @a INT = 4
DECLARE @b INT = 2
DECLARE @resultado INT 
SELECT @resultado = @a % @b
IF @resultado = 0
    PRINT @resultado
ELSE IF @resultado = 1
    PRINT @resultado
ELSE
    PRINT 'ERROR'
```

Comment: gracias hermano me funciono :)